# How to use multiple inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a single sql command to display the statements of accounts of one of the customer using inner join? help please, thanks.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to learn it in [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp), you will find it very easy !

Comment: Are you expecting us to do your homework? What have you tried yet?

Comment: I tried this one but it display 0 rows. 
SELECT statement_vatable, statement_vat, total FROM statement_of_account_tbl
INNER JOIN official_receipt_tbl ON statement_of_account_tbl.statement_acc_no=official_receipt_tbl.statement_acc_no
INNER JOIN customer_tbl ON official_receipt_tbl.cus_tel_no=customer_tbl.cus_tel_no
WHERE cus_tel_no = 422-9418

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your custumers are identified by the telephone number, i don't think that is a good idea, since telephone number can change quite often in your custumer table, anyway this should be the query.

```
SELECT SA.* FROM STATAMENT_OF_ACCOUNT_TBL SA 
JOIN OFFICIAL_RECEIP_TBL R ON SA.STATEMENT_ACC_NO=R.STATEMENT_ACC_NO
JOIN CUSTUMER_TBL C ON C.CUS_TEL_NO=R.CUS_TEL_NO
WHERE C.CUS_TEL_NO='422-9418'
```

Ah, and there should not be null on the keys you are trying to join or it could result in nothing as results.

Comment: is this also possible? SELECT statement_vatable, statement_vat, total FROM statement_of_account_tbl
INNER JOIN official_receipt_tbl ON statement_of_account_tbl.statement_acc_no=official_receipt_tbl.statement_acc_no
INNER JOIN customer_tbl ON official_receipt_tbl.cus_tel_no=customer_tbl.cus_tel_no
WHERE cus_tel_no = 422-9418

Comment: i see that you didn't put quotas around '422-9418' and sql server could interpret it as an int value , the difference of int values, moreover cust_tel_no should be qualified with the table name.

Comment: yes , as i already said , you have to specify the table name cus_tel_no belogns to. CUSTUMER_TBL.cus_tel_no='422-9418'